# My SVG Animation is getting cut off

Tags: jquery, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm new to SVG animation, and I'm having an issue with an SVG circle getting cut off during it's animation. Would anybody know the cause of this?

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/ZLdzpy)

```
TweenMax.to(".ease-out", 6, {x:600, ease:Back.easeOut});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the width within the SVG tag to be 100%.

```
<SVG width="100%"></SVG>
```